# How to dynamically load phtml file on a button click in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, phtml, modal

I have a phtml file `view.php` and its block class `View.php`. I need to show that phtml on a modal on checkout page and to do that I'm pre-loading 
 phtml file using following code :

```
<div id="modal-form" >
    <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('XYZ_module::view.phtml')) ?>
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Some Title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#modal-form'));
        }
    );
</script>
```

And then I'm opening this modal using following code :

```
$(".someBtn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-form').modal('openModal');
});
```

Right now everything is working from loading in the phtml file, in the modal and opening that modal on a button click.
What's not working is the functions of `View.php` block class.
I think the issue is with the pre-loading in phtml file using **include** function and because of that the php functions are hitting the server once and not when I actually open the modal.
Can I reload or just load that phtml file dynamically when the modal opens on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to set a default block and add your template to it.

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")
              ->setTemplate("XYZ_module::view.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```